# How to format Get-Date Day as 2 digits in Powershell

Tags: powershell, date, formatting

I try to get the Day as a two digit number out of Get-Date in PowerShell.

When I try `(Get-Date).Day` the result will be for example 6 but I want to have it as 06. Also for the month.

How can this be done?

I have already tried things like `(Get-Date).Day.ToString("dd")` but it doesn't work.

Comment: `Get-Date -Format "dd"`, `Get-Date -Format "dd-MM"`. You *can* format the numbers individually, if you so choose, but then you need format strings suitable to integers: `(Get-Date).Day.ToString("00")`.

Comment: Thank you for the fast answear. (Get-Date).Day.ToString("00") was exactly what I'm looking for!

Comment: (Get-Date).ToString("dd") is less typing :)

Answer (score 1):

Using `ToString()` and supplying date formatters (e.g. "yyyy" or "dd") will only work on dates. By accessing `.Day` or `.Year`, the operation is instead attempted on an integer, which will fail.

Try (for the day):

```
(Get-Date).ToString("dd")
```

...and (and for the month):

```
(Get-Date).ToString("MM")
```

See [here for custom formatting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings?redirectedfrom=MSDN) of dates using `ToString()`